# htaccess redirect to https not working in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I found a lot of similar answers but so far I could not solve the right thing that I want. It seems very easy or maybe somebody already answered but for me it's not working.

I've solved redirect to https on TLD (`http://example.com` to `https://www.example.com` and `https://example.com` to `https://example.com`)

But my htaccess code doesn't redirect to `https://www.example.com/whatever` from `http://example.com/whatever` or `https://example.com/whatever`.

In other words, everything must be redirected to `https://www`

Here's my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\\.php|resources|robots\\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I'm using codeigniter 3.11, in config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
$config['base_url'] .= "://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

Is there any mistake on my `.htaccess`?

Comment: Have you tried putting the rewrite rules that redirects to https first in your htaccess? The rules in your htaccess will be parsed from top to bottom, so if it finds a matching rule, like your `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]`, it will execute that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've solved redirect to https on TLD (`http://example.com` to `https://www.example.com` and `https://example.com` to `https://example.com`)

(I assume you mean `https://www.example.com/` in the last URL. And by "TLD" you really mean the "root directory" (or "document root" or "homepage").)

The only reason this works is that the first rule (the internal rewrite to `index.php` - the front-controller) is not triggered when requesting the document root. (`index.php` is served by mod_dir instead in this case.)

However, you don't appear to have tested `http://www.example.com/` (HTTP + www) which would have resulted in a broken redirect to `https://www.www.example.com` (doubling the www).

> ```
> RewriteCond $1 !^(index\\.php|resources|robots\\.txt)
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
> RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
> ```

Your rules are in completely the wrong order. The canonical redirects need to be *before* your rewrite to the CI front-controller, otherwise they are simply never processed for requests to non-assets (since the request is routed to `index.php` first - the CI front-controller).

However, the canonical redirects themselves are also in the wrong order (and/or incorrect) since a request for `http://www.example.com/` (HTTP + www) would be erroneously redirected to `https://www.www.example.com/` (as already mentioned above).

*Aside:* You also have erroneous double backslashes in the regex (*CondPattern*) of the first *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive). This would match a literal backslash - which will never happen, so the first *condition* is *always* successful (since it's a negated expression).

Your rules should be something like this instead:

```
# Canonical redirects

# non-www to www (and HTTPS)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


# Front-controller
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

This assumes you are *not* implementing [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) by minimising the number of canonical redirects. (If you do implement HSTS then you need to reverse the two rules - canonical redirects - above as you need to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS on the same host *first* - which would potentially result in two redirects when requesting HTTP + non-www.)

I also modified the HTTP to HTTPS redirect to be consistent with your non-www to www rule, ie. to use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead of a backreference. For some reason you were using a backreference in one and `REQUEST_URI` in the other, with different regex. `^` is more efficient than `.*` here as you simply need the rule to be successful, you don't need to actually match anything.